# What is this plant with thin leaves and a swollen woody stem?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I would like to know what is the name of this plant with long thin strap-shaped leaves which grow in clusters from a swollen stem that looks like a large woody bulb.  The "bulb" is halfway out of the soil in the pot.

[image: Unknown plant]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This plant is [Beaucarnea recurvata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaucarnea_recurvata), the ponytail palm.  Despite the name it is not related to the palms.  These are great indoor plants if you have good or high light conditions.  I have never had a lot of problems with them. Things to note include:

- in indoor environments it can be too dry ( Less than 30% relative humidity) and the tips tend to brown.  Once you cut the tip back to living tissue it too can die back so you get in an endless round of scissor work.  Better to leave the dead ends.
- most common cause of death is over watering. The plant stores water in the bulb at the base of the plant. Just checking to see if the soil is dry will not be an accurate reflection of whether the plant needs more water. Best solution is to place in a high light area so it uses more water and water less frequently.  (For example, every two weeks in high light).
- The most common pest is [mealybug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug) which will hide in the central axil where all new growth comes from. I have never successfully controlled mealybug on these plants with soap and water because you cannot get the soap where the eggs are hiding.

Comment: They are a succulent, related to Agave. And if you live in the right climate, can get pretty big (25ft). The base is water storage.

Comment: About the mealy-  I had trouble on my ponytail with soap/chemical control until one summer I treated it and left it outside.  Bugs in the yard came in and cleaned it out for me, haven't seen any mealy in a couple years since. Make sure you treat the interior column well to wash out as many eggs as you can with warm to slightly hot water (removes the protective coating).

Comment: One more thing about the ponytail palm that is really cool — they're simple to propagate. They produce pups at the bottom that can be removed from the original and repotted. If you use a clean knife and just slice the pup off (ideally one around 4-6" tall), it should root in cactus mix fairly easily. Source: [Propagating Ponytail Palms](http://www.epicgardening.com/ponytail-palm-beaucarnea-recurvata/)

Answer (score 1):

It is Nolyna Palm. It is also called lota Palm in hindi.it is a much loved indoor potted plant. In the open ground it can achieve a height of 9-10 feet.

Comment: Also known as Beaucarnea recurvata or the Pony Tail palm